# Can't conncet to WCF service from .NET CORE Web API in Docker

Tags: c#, docker, wcf, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have **WCF** service. Next, I have **.NET CORE WEB API** project. Web API calls WCF service. In local evrything works fine. Then I put **Web API in docker container**, Web API works, but it **can't communicate** with **WCF** service.

In past verisons evrything works normaly with docker. I checked, docker container has access to the intenet (ping, wget...).

Dcoker version:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        6247962
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:31 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:13:06 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Error from API:

```
 An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Cannot assign requested address 
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Cannot assign requested address
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceModelHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpClientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.SendRequestAsync(Message message, TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

And here is my docker file - the same file worked before:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ["BlackFoxWebAPI/KerasEvaluator.zip", "/app/"]
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["BlackFoxWebAPI/BlackFoxWebAPI.csproj", "BlackFoxWebAPI/"]
COPY ["BlackFoxWebAPIModels/BlackFoxWebAPIModels.csproj", "BlackFoxWebAPIModels/"]
COPY ["KerasAPIClient/KerasAPIClient.csproj", "KerasAPIClient/"]
RUN dotnet restore "BlackFoxWebAPI/BlackFoxWebAPI.csproj"
COPY . .

WORKDIR "/src/BlackFoxWebAPI"
RUN dotnet build "BlackFoxWebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "BlackFoxWebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BlackFoxWebAPI.dll"]
```

Comment: Where did you host the wcf service? If you request a method which not invoke wcf service, will it work? Try to run `docker logs containername` and share us the result .

Comment: @TaoZhou 
1. wcf service is hosted on a remote machine - not in docker.
2. If request a method which not invoke wcf service it works
3. _Error from API:_  is log from container

Comment: Share us the code for request wcf service, do you implement any security for the wcf service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The problem was setting service reference in Visual Studio. After changing WCF address in  `ConnectedService.json` you have to update Microsoft WCF provider for each enviroment. I didn't update docker relese env, and relese used some old reference - **NOT** reference from `ConnectedService.json`.